# Remove an attribute from xaml using c# - WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, attributes

This question is related to removing an attribute in xaml.
In the below code, I have a Span. During an event, I add a back ground to this Span. During another event, I need to remove it. Please let me know, if there is a way to remove the background attribute I set to Span.

My Xaml looks like this.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication4.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication4"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="40"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RichTextBox x:Name="rtb">
        <FlowDocument>
            <Paragraph>
                <Span x:Name="def" Tag="default">
                    <Run x:Name="deg">Some Text</Run>
                </Span>
            </Paragraph>
        </FlowDocument>
    </RichTextBox>
    <TextBox x:Name="tx" Grid.Row="1" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
    <Grid Grid.Row="2">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Button Content="s" Click="Button_Click"/>
        <Button Content="bg-Add" Grid.Column="1" Click="Button_Click"/>
        <Button Content="bg-Remove" Grid.Column="2" Click="Button_Click"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>

</Window>
```

My code looks like this.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Markup;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.  Shapes;

namespace WpfApplication4
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((sender as Button).Content.ToString() == "s")
        {
            tx.Text = XamlWriter.Save(def);
        }
        else if ((sender as Button).Content.ToString() == "bg-Add")
        {
                def.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue);
        }
        else if ((sender as Button).Content.ToString() == "bg-Remove")
        {
            //Need to remove the set back color so that I get the default back
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I am able to find an answer myself.

```
def.ClearValue(Span.BackgroundProperty);
```

is going to remove that attribute for me.

Comment: Just a note. What you call attribute is actually a property, or more precisely a WPF dependency property. This is why you can call ClearValue. If it was an ordinary CLR property, it would still be settable in XAML, but there wouldn't be a ClearValue method.

Answer (score 1):

You can override ShouldSerializeProperty

```
public class CustomizedSpan : Span
{

    public bool IsRemoveBackGround;

    protected override bool ShouldSerializeProperty(DependencyProperty dp)
    {
        if (dp == Span.BackgroundProperty && IsRemoveBackGround)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {

            return base.ShouldSerializeProperty(dp);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing this option. Something new I learnt today.